# I want to limit my SQL query based on a column

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-order-by, inner-join, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables, one named user and the other named payment. A user can have multiple payments.
example:
user 1 with 2 payments
user 2 with 5 payments
user 3 with 10 payments
user 4 with 7 payments

I have this query:

```
select * from user inner join payment on payment.user_id = user.id limit 2
```

The query will return only user 1 with his 2 payments.

But I want to return user 1 and user 2, each with their payments.

Comment: Are you just looking for the `WHERE` keyword?  If you're not familiar with it then you should *definitely* be starting with some introductory MySQL tutorials.  If you *are* familiar with it then it's not clear to me what you're asking.

Comment: This might be an example of the [tag:greatest-n-per-group] type of question, which comes up every week on Stack Overflow. I suggest you click on that tag link and see if the existing answers give you what you need.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, you want to return the payments of two users, if so, try this:

```
select p.*
from payment p
inner join (
  select id
  from user
  order by id
  limit 2
) as u on u.id = p.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running MySQL 8.0.14 or higher, that's a good spot for a [lateral join](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html):

```
select u.*, p.*
from users u
cross join lateral (
    select p.*
    from payments p 
    where p.user_id = u.id
    order by p.payment_date desc
    limit 2
) p
where u.id in (1, 2)
order by u.id, p.payment_date
```

Notes:

- you do want to use `order by` with `limit` (otherwise the database may not return consistent results); I assumed an `payment_date` column in the `payments` table for this purpose, so this gives you the two latest payments per user (for the record, your initial code has the same problem, and there is no guarantee that it will consistently return the same result when ran multiple times against the same dataset)
- for performance, consider an index on `payment(user_id, payment_date desc)`
- when joining multiple tables, it is good practice to enumerate the columns you want in the resultset, rather than using `*` - this clarifies the intent, and avoids conflicts when columns have the same name in different tables
- `user` is a [keyword in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html), hence a bad choice for a column name (`users` is not, for example)

---

In earlier versions of MySQL 8.0, an alternative is `row_number()` (which might scale less efficiently if there are many payments per user):

```
select u.*, p.*
from users u
inner join (
    select p.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by user_id order by payment_date desc) rn
    from payments p
) p on p.user_id = u.id 
where u.id in (1, 2) and p.rn <= 2
order by u.id, p.payment_date
```